# Some activities stay open in the "android history" when starting a new one

Tags: android, debugging, android-activity, history

So when I open a certain activity, the main activity stays in the "android history" and it looks like this, now there are two instances of the app:

[image: the android "history" where the main activity stays]

But with other activities it just skip to it (like I want) and stays with only one instance

[image: the android "history" where the main activity disappear like I want]

Anyone know why does it do that? I tried to call 
" finish(); ", 
I tried 
" android:noHistory="true" "
, but none of them works..

Comment: If it's not clear: the activity doubles itself in the "android history" with the main activity staying and the new one openning, why does it do that while sometimes it works perfectly fine?

Comment: How do you start each activity? Please show some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the launch mode of your activity in your AndroidManifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```

Refer to this documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Oh well I actually had to remove the "singleInstance part" but it works! But now when i press back the activity reappears and I have to press back 2 times to get to the main activity..

Comment: Okay I fixed that it was my bad. Thanks for the answer though! Super fast :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help you